# multiple buttons with same form at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple buttons that has a same class. When clicking the button, there's a form popups. how can I make it dynamic? so whenever I click a button not all form will popup.

See sample code below.

```js
$(".plans-de-mesure-form-button").click(function(){
  $(".evaluation-gratuite-form").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
a.plans-de-mesure-form-button {
    cursor:pointer;
 }

.evaluation-gratuite-form {
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="listing">
   <a class="plans-de-mesure-form-button">Evaluation</a>
  <div class="evaluation-gratuite-form">
  <form>
   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
   <br>
   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
   </form>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="listing">
   <a class="plans-de-mesure-form-button">Evaluation</a>
  <div class="evaluation-gratuite-form">
  <form>
   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
   <br>
   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
   </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

up to your structure you can use  `$(this)`  and `.next()`

```
$(".plans-de-mesure-form-button").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".evaluation-gratuite-form").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

to close the form

```
$('.Close_Button_Class').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest(".evaluation-gratuite-form").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way `$(this).next(".evaluation-gratuite-form")`

```js
$(".plans-de-mesure-form-button").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".evaluation-gratuite-form").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
a.plans-de-mesure-form-button {
    cursor:pointer;
 }

.evaluation-gratuite-form {
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="listing">
   <a class="plans-de-mesure-form-button">Evaluation</a>
  <div class="evaluation-gratuite-form">
  <form>
   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
   <br>
   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
   </form>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="listing">
   <a class="plans-de-mesure-form-button">Evaluation</a>
  <div class="evaluation-gratuite-form">
  <form>
   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
   <br>
   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
   </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

More Elegant solution will be that which is DOM independent because there can be more elements who are siblings.
Use parents instead of parent function if a tag is present at nested levels.
So use below code:

```js
$(".plans-de-mesure-form-button").click(function(){
  $(this).parent('.listing').find(".evaluation-gratuite-form").fadeIn("slow");
});
```